# How can I access same named child elements in firebase without giving parent name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database like this

[image]

I want to access only basic data from all children without writing their id. I used this code block and it worked. But very slow.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      staffsBasics: [],
    };
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.database().ref('staff-list').on('value', (snap) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < snap.numChildren(); i++) {
        firebase.database().ref("staff-list/" + i + "/basic").on("value", (snap) => {
          this.setState({
            staffsBasics: [...this.state.staffsBasics, snap.val()]
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Is there a better way to access only same named child elements?

I tried `orderbychild` but it gives all data too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you read a certain location from Firebase, the data snapshot you get contains all information under that location. So there's no need to make nested API calls to get data from under `/staff-list/i`.

With this knowledge, you code could become:

```
firebase.database().ref('staff-list').on('value', (snap) => {
  snap.forEach((child) => {
    this.setState({
      staffsBasics: [...this.state.staffsBasics, child.val().basics]
    });
  }
});
```

If you find you regularly needs this, consider changing your data structure to better fit the use-case, as you're downloading more data than is needed right now.

For example, I'd consider having separate higher-level lists (`staff-list-basics`, `staff-list-details`, etc) with the same child keys, and then only loading from that one.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The point is; i want only "basic" elements of all childs. i have (for example) 50 childs and every child has tree elements: "basic", "details" and "files". in my example i decided to use "for loop" but don't know how many childs at the beginning. So first i tried to learn how many childs with "snap.numChildren()" then i used this return in the for loop and access only the "basic" elements of each child. 
in your reply i render all database, don't i? if i didn't understand your reply, could u please write more detail please, thanks...

Comment: Ah got it, I missed that you were only adding one note to the state. I update the code for that, and added some notes on how to possibly optimize the data structure for this use-case.

Comment: yes i could, but if i couldn't, there must be a more simple solution. Also i thought like u but i just tried not to change my lists, anyway solution is solution. Thanks again...